# django: css in static folder shows 404 error but not js files

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, I have a working django application in the public server.

Now I want to make it work in the local server.

so,

I downloaded all the files from the server

I installed virtualenv, installed same django version as in the public server.
Changed username and password for mysql database
It works,

but
Style is not applied.
I have every static files in static folder, it's in the same location as manage.py

If view the source, It appears like this

```
<script src='/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='/static/js/bootstrap.min.js' async defer></script>
<link href='/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' async>
```

If I right click and open the js files it works, but if I open css file it shows 404 error.

Why is that only css is not working

In settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

In the main urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Please tell me if you need to any other info, because I dont know what is very relevant for this question.

My project structure:

```
myprojectfolder/
    app1/
    app2/
    static/
        css/bootstrap.css
        js/bootstrap.js
```

and since I am running apache, I changed the ownership of the files www-data with the command

```
sudo chown -R sugumar:www-data myprojectfolder
```

Comment: Are js files serving?

Comment: @doubleo46 js is available if open in separate tab

Comment: Show us your directories structure? And btw, are you sure your application has read permission on these css files?

Comment: @Sraw I have updated my question with the directory structure

Comment: Um... it won't be your true structure as `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` are obviously different name. Or this problem is just caused by a typo?

Comment: @Sraw  it is blueprint of my directory structure, I have not used real app names and js names, but the directory structure is same

Comment: I mean, if your file is named `bootstrap.css`, then you cannot access it by `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css` but `/static/css/bootstrap.css`. I just want to confirm that this typo is not the cause.

Comment: @Sraw Yes it's typo issue, now it's working thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: if you are using apache you need to define aliases for /static and /media in your apache-config. the static and media in your settings-file just defines what django will replace your {% static %} template tags with. it won't be able to serve the files (which would by the way be much too non-performant).
Edit: did nod see that it was solved already. sorry.